# Sorting Datagrid with DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am using a DataGrid and the ItemSource is Bound to a list of strings.
The problem is that the sorting is not working. 
The header is enabled and can be clicked but the data is not sorted.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentName}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="400" CanUserSort="True"  SortMemberPath="Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Name" Foreground="#FF40A4E0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

I think the problem is **SortMemberPath="Name"** but I dont know what to put instead of "Name"

Comment: Have you tried sorting without the member path? That field is reserved for the property name you intend to sort by. Since it's just a simple string collection, you wouldn't have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can set `SortMemberPath="."`. This usage is similar when you set the Binding's `Path` to `"."`, which means the whole item will be bound, in this case the whole item will be used as the input value for the sorter.