# Column with a stack panel and triggers not following column rules

Tags: wpf, xaml

It has been over 5 years since I last did anything with WPF and I am a bit rusty. That said, I seem to have jumped into the deep end too soon and have done something I can't figure out.

I have a hierarchical DataGrid that works pretty well except that the column isn't quite following the rules all the other columns in a row are following, ie when a row is selected, all of the columns in the row display a different background color to indicate the selected row except the second column, which continues to show the row/alternate row color pattern, as if it was not in the selected row.  Can someone point out where I went wrong?

````
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f5f5f5"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6e6e6e"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#6e6e6e"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#6e6e6e"/>
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#f5f5f5"/>
            <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6e6e6e"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CommonColumnElementStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>        
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:IndentBasedOnLevel x:Key="IndentBasedOnLevel"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#316dff"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Name="HierarchialDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" ColumnWidth="*">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Device" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Data.Name}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" 
                                                          Margin="{Binding Level,Converter={StaticResource IndentBasedOnLevel}}"
                                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ClickMode="Press">
                                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="19"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="13"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                                    <Border Width="19" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
                                                                        <Border Width="11" Height="11"
                                                                              BorderThickness="0"
                                                                              BorderBrush="#FF7898B5"
                                                                              CornerRadius="1"
                                                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="true">                                                                            
                                                                            <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
                                                                            Margin="1,1,1,1"
                                                                            Fill="Black"
                                                                            Data="M 0 0 L 9 5 L 0 9 Z"/>                                                                            
                                                                        </Border>
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                                                        
                                                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                                                            Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform"
                                                                                TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"
                                                                                     CenterY="3"
                                                                                     CenterX="3" />
                                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                                            </Setter>
                                                                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                                                                TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                                                                Value="Black" />                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                            <Setter Property="Data"
                                                                            TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                                                            Value="M 0 7 L 7 0 L 0 0 Z"/>                                                                            
                                                                        </Trigger>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                                            </ToggleButton>
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasChildren}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>                                                
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alias" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Data.Alias}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deplyment Group" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Data.DeploymentGroup}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Is Configured  " Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Data.IsConfigured}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transfer Configuration" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Data.TransferConfiguration}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transfer Status  " Width="*" Binding="{Binding Data.TransferStatus}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Host Status  " Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Data.HostStatus}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Transfer Update" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Data.LastTransferUpdate}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnElementStyle}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>        
    </Grid>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Device column shouldn't be a [DataGridTextColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn) (hosts textual content) since it displaying more than just text. Like your first column, you should use a [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn) (hosts template-specified content).

Here's what I get when displaying an ObservableCollection of String:
[image]

As a **reference**, here is my XAML for that column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Device"
                     Width="*">

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              ClickMode="Press">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable"
                                    Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="Width"
                                    Value="19" />
                            <Setter Property="Height"
                                    Value="13" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Width="19"
                                                Height="13"
                                                Background="Transparent">
                                            <Border Width="11"
                                                    Height="11"
                                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                                    BorderBrush="#FF7898B5"
                                                    CornerRadius="1"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                                <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
                                                      Margin="1,1,1,1"
                                                      Fill="Black"
                                                      Data="M 0 0 L 9 5 L 0 9 Z" />
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform"
                                                        TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180"
                                                                         CenterY="3"
                                                                         CenterX="3" />
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill"
                                                        TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                                        Value="Black" />
                                                <Setter Property="Data"
                                                        TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                                        Value="M 0 7 L 7 0 L 0 0 Z" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This doesn't include the some of the properties your original XAML had so it won't work as-is, you will have to adjust your XAML directly instead of copying this as-is.

Comment: @davecove answer has been updated.

Comment: Almost perfect... for some reason this column no longer raises the Sorting event...  I am custom sorting that column and need to catch the event to do a hierarchical sort (children sorted inside of parent nodes all the way down).

Comment: @davecove maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575140/sorting-datagrid-with-datagridtemplatecolumn) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095836/wpf-how-do-i-sort-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-with-a-list-of-strings-as-content) helps?

Comment: The first link was the fix. Thank you!